# Update checkbox at click event vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a checkbox function.I am getting the value from backend. When i click the checkbox it makes a post or delete call based on the checkbox is checked or not.Then i am getting the updated value and displaying.But seems like the checkbox is not always displaying updated value.The api seems like correct but the value is not always updating.

```
    <td v-for="test in tests">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="test.checked" @click="update(test.checked)">
      </div>
    </td>

    data() {
      return {
        tests:[],
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getData();
    },
    methods: {
      getData() {
          const data = await axios.get('getdata')          
      },
      update(checked) {
        if(!checked){
          const data = await axios.post('checktrue');
        } else {
          axios.delete('checkfalse')
        }
        this.getData();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td v-for="(test, index) in tests" :key="index">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="test.checked" @click="update(test.checked)">
  </div>
</td>
```

Adding the key to the for loop should fix this, because vue v-for loops are a bit tricky. They can't really detect any change in objects. However it should detect, that the indexes change and rerender accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have added :key="index" but unfortunately  the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

try with below answer:

```
<td v-for="test in tests">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="test.checked" @click="update(!test.checked)">
  </div>
</td>
```